# what does << mean in sprite kit collision categories?

Tags: sprite-kit

My friend said that he implemented some code so that my collision detection would work better. What he put in I don't understand so I wanted to know what it means. More specifically what `<<` means.

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, CollisionCategory){
rectangulo = (1 << 0),
circulo = (1 << 1)
```

thanks,
<3

Comment: More appropriate tags are [bit-flags], [bitmask],and [bit-shift].

Comment: @Jessy - I guess if he'd known to add those tags, he wouldn't have had to ask the question :-)

Comment: I would have added them for him, but I didn't have enough rep at that point. The idea was that, given those tags, the question would be answered faster and more completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is totally unrelated to Xcode or sprite collision; the `<<` is the `C` language left shift operator. If, as in your case, applied to integers, it performs a bitwise shift of the first argument by the second argument. In your case, the two expressions yield 1 and 2, respectively.